# Passing data between ViewControllerB to ViewControllerA, Delegate not get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

i tried use delegate with out success, the delegate is not called.
here is my delegate code:

setting the delegate (ViewControllerB)

```
@class SearchGardenTable;
@protocol SearchGardenDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(SearchGardenTable *)controller didFinishWithGardenID:(NSString *)gardenID gardenName:(NSString*)gardenName andCityName:(NSString*)cityName;
@end

@interface SearchGardenTable : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SearchGardenDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

telling VC B that VC A is its delegate:

```
 // in VC A viewDidLoad.
self.searchGarden = [[SearchGardenTable alloc]init];
[self.searchGarden setDelegate:self];
```

VC A adopts the protocol

```
@interface AddKid () <MZFormSheetBackgroundWindowDelegate,SearchGardenDelegate>

@end

@implementation AddKid
```

setting the parameters i want to pass back from VC B to VC A:

```
    _kidGaedenID  = [temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _kidGardenName = [temp1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishWithGardenID:_kidGaedenID gardenName:_kidGardenName andCityName:_kidCityName];
```

implement the protocol method at VC A:

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(SearchGardenTable *)controller didFinishWithGardenID:(NSString *)gardenID gardenName:(NSString*)gardenName andCityName:(NSString*)cityName
{
    _kidGardenID = gardenID;
    _gardenName.text = gardenName;
    _kidCity.text = cityName;

}
```

**EDIT**

```
ViewController B didSelectRowAtIndexPath: code

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

        NSArray *temp = [_responseDict valueForKey:@"ID"];
        NSArray *temp1 = [_responseDict valueForKey:@"name"];

        _kidGaedenID  = [temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        _kidGardenName = [temp1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



        [[self delegate] addItemViewController:self didFinishWithGardenID:_kidGaedenID gardenName:_kidGardenName andCityName:_kidCityName];

        [self mz_dismissFormSheetControllerAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(MZFormSheetController *formSheetController) {

//dismiss the popup view which i create it VC A with that gitHub package:
https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController/issues/98

        }];
```

**EDIT 2**
the code that present ViewControllerB :

```
- (IBAction)chooseGardenAndCityBtn:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modal"];

    MZFormSheetController *formSheet = [[MZFormSheetController alloc] initWithViewController:vc];

    formSheet.presentedFormSheetSize = CGSizeMake(300, 298);
    //    formSheet.transitionStyle = MZFormSheetTransitionStyleSlideFromTop;
    formSheet.shadowRadius = 2.0;
    formSheet.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    formSheet.shouldDismissOnBackgroundViewTap = YES;
    formSheet.shouldCenterVertically = YES;
    formSheet.movementWhenKeyboardAppears = MZFormSheetWhenKeyboardAppearsCenterVertically;
    // formSheet.keyboardMovementStyle = MZFormSheetKeyboardMovementStyleMoveToTop;
    // formSheet.keyboardMovementStyle = MZFormSheetKeyboardMovementStyleMoveToTopInset;
    // formSheet.landscapeTopInset = 50;
    // formSheet.portraitTopInset = 100;

    __weak MZFormSheetController *weakFormSheet = formSheet;


    // If you want to animate status bar use this code
    formSheet.didTapOnBackgroundViewCompletionHandler = ^(CGPoint location) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)weakFormSheet.presentedFSViewController;
        if ([navController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[SearchCityTable class]]) {
            SearchCityTable *mzvc = (SearchCityTable *)navController.topViewController;
            mzvc.showStatusBar = NO;
        }


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            if ([weakFormSheet respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
                [weakFormSheet setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
            }
        }];
    };

    formSheet.willPresentCompletionHandler = ^(UIViewController *presentedFSViewController) {
        // Passing data
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)presentedFSViewController;
        navController.topViewController.title = @"בחר עיר";
    };
    formSheet.transitionStyle = MZFormSheetTransitionStyleCustom;

    [MZFormSheetController sharedBackgroundWindow].formSheetBackgroundWindowDelegate = self;

    [self mz_presentFormSheetController:formSheet animated:YES completionHandler:^(MZFormSheetController *formSheetController) {

    }];



}
```

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Did you specify that VC A adopts the SearchGardenDelegate protocol?

Comment: yes i did..
see me edit.

Comment: where are you messaging the delegate method from? From which method in your VC B class?

Comment: where u have this  [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishWithGardenID:_kidGaedenID gardenName:_kidGardenName andCityName:_kidCityName];

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: tableview method

Comment: Is the code breaking inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: Whether both view controller A and B are UITableViewController Subclass?

Comment: @DanSpag is, the code is inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @KathiravanG no. only B use UITableViewController.

Comment: Might be worth to have a look in more detail at these view controllers implementations. Are they in storyboards or xibs?

Comment: storyboards. tell me what you want to see i ll update my post

Comment: after dismissing the pop view what u did?

Comment: the popup dismissed then the delegate protocol method should called..
in the package i use there is a block which should handle the dismissed popup, but i try without success to use it.

Comment: How u say it not getting called?

Comment: what you mean? the delegate not getting called in VC A after i dismiss the popup (VC B).

Comment: I think you need an exit segue to pass the information back to the vc - You might need to read some more about view controllers and segues because what started off as a delegate / protocol question has ended up a segue question. In essence trying to use a protocol delegate to pass information between view controllers when Apple have given us a similar method to 'prepare for segue' is a bit crazy. Google Exit segue and see the correct way to capture property values from a (segued) view controller on exit. It's similar to protocol but better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing

```
self.searchGarden = [[SearchGardenTable alloc]init];
```

But you said you have your view controllers in a storyboard. This makes me think self.searchGarden at the point of viewDidLoad: is a different object from the one in the storyboard.

You should assign an object to self.searchGarden when you are preparing to push your VC B or before performingTheSegue (if you are using a segue).

**EDIT**

From your code I assume that

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modal"];
```

is your VC B, so you need to do vc.delegate = self; 
Just keep in mind that your vc has to be of type VC B, which in your case is SearchGardenTable

**EDIT 2**

Given the current setup, the quickest solution that comes in to my mind now, is a NSNotification. From your VC B send a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"userDidTapOnCell" object:nil userInfo:dictionaryOfObjects];
```

Where your dictionary of objects is initialized with the objects you retrieved from your model, like:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"gardenID": _kidGaedenID, @"gardenName": _kidGardenName };
```

Than in VC A you add yourself as an observer to the notification on viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gardenInfoDidComeBack:) name:@"userDidTapOnCell" object:nil];
```

and implement the method:

```
- (void)gardenInfoDidComeBack:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    // retrieve the kidGardenID and kidGardenName from the dict and use them as you whish.
}
```

Hope this helps you to accomplish your task. Probably the architecture of your navigation is not the best, but this goes beyond the scope of this topic which has gone far enough already.

Comment: i have a property in ViewControllerA
@property (nonatomic, strong) SearchGardenTable *searchGarden;

Comment: I can see that. But you are initialising in viewDidLoad to a new VC B instance, so it's probably different from the one you are displaying. Would be worth to have a look at the code you wrote to push VC B from VC A

Comment: It's still missing the code in which you push VC B from VC A

Comment: edit again, now with all the code for present the VC B popup.

Comment: i change it to    SearchGardenTable *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modal"];
    vc.delegate = self;    is that ok? or how should i do that? thank you bro

Comment: @OshriALM if you don't need to message that VC again than it's fine, otherwise I would do:  `self.searchGarden = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modal"];` Anyway, does it work?

Comment: no :/
I'm starting to go crazy! what could cause this problem?
i've tried everything.

Comment: @OshriALM You are missing something very basic in here my friend. Are you sure the storyboard with the identifier main is indeed the correct view controller? IS the correct class set in the identity inspector tab?

Comment: i dont know if its can affect, but "modal" its a navigationController that lead to "CityTableView" and then "SearchGardenTable".
VC A create the popup then i have 3 views Nav view city and then garden which has the delegate

Comment: @OshriALM so you are setting the delegate here completely wrong. You can do a) initialize your SearchGardenTable VC and provide that instance to the navigation controller or b) take the values and bring them down to the delegate VC. Just out of curiosity, since you are not accessing the particular SearchGardenTable from your VC A, how ever would you set the delegate properly? Is there any code you can show us where you assign the view controllers to the Navigation controller or are they embedded using the storyboard?

Comment: they embedded using the storyboard..
see my edit, i added a photo.
i need to pass back data from searchGarden to VC A (which present "modal")

Comment: @OshriALM see my EDIT 2.

Comment: holy **** i dont belive i over this issue.
thank you very much bro, i really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

Please show your VC B initialisation.

Make sure that self.searchGarden is initialised before you calling this line

```
self.searchGarden.delegate = self; // in VC A viewDidLoad.
```

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but did you try:

```
 [[self delegate] addItemViewController:self didFinishWithGardenID:_kidGaedenID gardenName:_kidGardenName andCityName:_kidCityName]];
```

instead of

```
 [self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishWithGardenID:_kidGaedenID gardenName:_kidGardenName andCityName:_kidCityName];
```

Comment: @property (nonatomic, weak) id <SearchGardenDelegate> delegate;   Weak???? I think this is being released before it gets used - Try Strong

Comment: Last attempt from me been told it should be assign and definitely not Strong don't know for certain.

Answer (score 0):

What i comes to know from your queries and concerns i found something

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    searchVC = (ControllerA *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"controllerA"];
    searchVC.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchVC animated:YES];
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: i cant use segue because ViewController B is a popup window which i implement with this package from gitHub MZFormSheetController.
and when i clicking on a cell in ViewControllerB and popup dismissed.
so i must prepare the data i want to pass before i dismiss the popUp window (VC B)

Comment: yes, collect your data at the place where you're clicking is perform you just need to call  *[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"controllerB" sender:self];* after you collected the your data. and it will call method *-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender*

Comment: but there is not a segue in the stroryboard between them.. as i said VC B is a popup on AC A.
i can still use prepareForSegue?